# Code-behind of my custom component is not running

Tags: android, ios, webpack, nativescript

The code-behind of my custom component is not being executed when bundling the app with WebPack (`tns run ios --bundle --env.snapshot --env.aot`). I followed the official documentation but I couldn't get it to work.

Can anyone help me, please?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr2yr.png) Example project: https://github.com/felipebueno/my-app

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8u50.png) Custom components documentation: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/basics#xml-based-custom-component-with-a-code-file

Screenshots for reference:

With webpack (example project. [Update] The name of the component is different but it's being imported properly):
[image]

Without webpack:
[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure here, but in your first screenshot, you're attempting to import `profile-icon-page`, but in your second screenshot, the component directory is named just `profile-icon`.

Comment: Oh, I accidentally changed the name of the component when creating the example project. But is't being imported correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the default webpack configuration (from nativescript-webpack [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/blob/50e1ad70ec2e666f3b739aea0123b995a7e6ee70/bundle-config-loader.js#L3)) will bundle only pages which are named to end with `-page` or `-root`. All other custom named pages and resources should be included explicitly n your `webpack.config.js` in the `CopyWebpackPlugin` array.

So as a solution **rename your custom component name** to end with **`-name`** postfix and make a clean rebuild. For example, in your case change the file name to `profile-icon-page` (and use the proper import)

Or add the custom resources as shown below in `webpack.config.js` file

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: "shared/components/**" }, // HERE
    { from: "fonts/**" },
    { from: "**/*.jpg" },
    { from: "**/*.png" },
]
```

Comment: It worked! I tried both solutions isolated but it only worked when I applied both. Thank you very much, Nick! I really appreciate it.